# Setting Cron Job

Tags: cron, crontrigger

I have requirement which say I need to set cron to run a job daily from monday to thursday twice i.e at 10 PM and 5 PM.And the same job should also run on friday 5 PM and on sunday at 10  PM

For the first part of the requirement I have set as " 0 22 * * 1-4"
But how do I set for the second requirment also ?

I need to set as a single cron line.
Please help/suggest.

Comment: This cannot be done in a single cronjob.

Comment: oh..ok..Thanks Then I will set as two cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple values for a field can be provided as comma separated values. 
For ex. "0 0 10,17 ? * MON-THU"
Here is one good link to refer:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html